# confusion matrix with sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, text-classification, confusion-matrix

I trained a model for spam filtering 
 I get confusion matrix with this line of code

```
tn, fp, fn, tp=  confusion_matrix(targets, predictions).ravel()
```

classifcation labels are put on a list as follows:

```
targets = test_set['S'].values
```

S values are classification labels for each email

and these are the results

[image: performance measures for DTree model]

I dont specify at any moment which class is positive et and which one is the  negative.. how do i know which is which ( is spam considered the positive class ) ?

Comment: i have multiple models, SVM,Naive Bayes and DecisionTree

Comment: Show your `targets` and `predictions`. They will be encoded internally alphabetically and the class which gets the `1` as the encoded number will be positive. Here your data contains `ham` and `spam`, then `ham` will be 0 and `spam` will be 1, so yes, spam is the positive class.

Comment: @VivekKumar are you sure ? i'm basing all my project evaluation on this..what do you mean by encoded internally alphabetically, can you explain more with reference ?

Comment: Yes. All scikit utilities which can handle string labels will internally use [LabelEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) which in turn will use [numpy.unique](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) to get all the unique classes.`numpy.unique` returns data in sorted manner.